# replace only part of string witg preg_replace

Tags: php, string, url, search, preg-replace

I have little problem with a replacement of a little part in an url.

I have an url with some queries that I build with http_build_query().

In that url i have a query like `angle_30`. What I want is to remove the `_30` so the query becomes `angle`.

How can I do that with preg_replace?

I have created a search and replacement array

```
$search_pattern = array();
$search_pattern[0] = "/([?&]newpage)=[^&]*/";
$search_pattern[1] = "/([?&]next)=[^&]*/"; 

$search_replacements = array();
$search_replacements[0] = ''; 
$search_replacements[1] = '';
```

which works fine. I just want to extend it with the angle replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a search and replacement pattern that replaces "`angle_`", followed by an arbitrary number of digits with "`angle`".

```
$search_pattern[2] = "/angle_\d+/";

$search_replacements[2] = "angle";
```

Comment: Garh... That easy! :) Thank you very much :)